# What are the advantages of greenplum for full disk scan?

Tags: greenplum

As we know GPDB distribute db items into several segments by a given hash key. I'm sure it will give better performance for conditional query, especially for those queries with given distributed key/field, because it can greatly reduce the scan scope.

But how about full disk scan? For example, `select count(distinct aField) from table`, or `select aField, count(distinct bField) from table group by aField`, ... and so on - queries without condition.

So all the segments are fully scanned, and query results will be sent to master for aggregation via network. What can we benefit from such case?

Comment: A database query is not a "disk scan".  Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: "Advantages" compared to what?

Comment: yes, full table scan, not disk scan. @Stephen C

Comment: Compared to storing all data in one postgresql db instance @Ancoron

Comment: @mik - So please update the Question to say this!!   Use the "edit" button.

Answer (score 2):

Greenplum processes sequential scans highly fast, and as your data is distributed across segments, this means that small pieces of data are being scanned in parallel by multiple segments.

Not to mention that you can organize your data with the correct "row/column" orientation approach, which could result in even smaller data to scan.

Also, if you're talking about huge volumes of data, you will probably use partitioned tables, which means even faster results.

Comment: Agreed (assuming full table scan, not disk, per Stephen).

Remember to Partition by Query Predicates -- Not Distribute. If you Partition by Query Predicates you reduce the amount of data to be scanned by each segment. If you Distribute by Query Predicates you reduce the number of segments active in the work (Processing Skew ).

Comment: @all: references?

Comment: @Ancoron here [link](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/500/admin_guide/ddl/ddl-index.html) , explanation by greenplum docs over indexes, gives some light into this discussion, saying almost exactly what I answered.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Brendan Stephens

Answer (score 0):

As Greenplum is a fork of PostgreSQL intended for [parallel query execution at multiple segments](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5180/admin_guide/query/topics/parallel-proc.html) - if actual queried data is spread across them - it can basically leverage from increased execution performance from the multiple disk systems and individual nodes' caches. The overhead of data sending to the master node and final query processing as well as the master node having to prepare each nodes' query and send it down for processing is usually small, but increases a lot if non-aggregation queries with final sort needs to be done by the master.

However, as they just recently [merged in version 9.4](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/commit/244dc0ad8152c8a3709fe57427bca4c36d146b48) of the upstream PostgreSQL code, the main issue of Greenplums' performance claims are that it compares to a PostgreSQL version that is too old for anyone that cares about performance and does not benefit from any of the [parallel query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-query.html) improvements that have been introduced starting with version 9.6.

The multiple segments per host also doesn't help much here as each of the segments know nothing about the other ones at the same host and hence, are competing for resources (disk I/O, memory operations, CPU caches, network, ...) or you actually have to [limit it a lot per segment as recommended](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5180/admin_guide/wlmgmt_intro.html), which can drive you crazy because some queries then just spill to disk for sorts. A properly configured single PostgreSQL 11 installation should outperform any number of Greenplum segments at a single node simply because it has more total cache available and it actually knows about it.

**TL;DR**

PostgreSQL upstream got a lot of improvements in recent years and for specific use cases, please consider using extensions rather than a complete fork.

Also, if you are concerned about the performance of a `count(distinct ...)` you should pay close attention to [how you are counting](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#distinct_counts).